# Cannot reset the work account's password because "password reset isn't properly set up for your organization."

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, reset-password

I'm in a bind with Azure login account. I've forgotten my password for my account that I use for a client's DevOps. It wasn't until I ended up created another account today to troubleshoot the problem that I might understand the issue, but still can't fix it.

About a year ago, my client added me as a Guest in their Active Directory. I did not have an active directory myself. I got the notice from Microsoft in an invite email to get started, which created an account to get access to their Azure Portal and DevOps. I've been logged in for a year, but was trying test a feature which required me to login to DevOps during the process. I tried what I thought was my password, but that didn't work. No problem, I'll just click on the reset password feature. That ended up informing me that "password reset isn't properly set up for your organization." Knowing who setup my account up, I ask them to reset my password. The response was we do not have control to reset your password because you're a guest.

Through several discussions, and seeing what was available to them, and how a Guest was set up, it was suggested to setup an account within Microsoft for the email. I did that, and when I went back to try and login to their portal, I was presented with two options after I entered my email address. There was a work account and a personal account. Both with the same email address. The work account indicated it was created by "your IT department". Which we did not create this, it was a result of the client adding us as a guest, then finishing the process to gain access. So I can only assume, either an active directory was created for my domain, or I was added to a generic active directory.

In either case, I still can't change the password for the work account, and researching has not helped, as it keeps resetting my personal account.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Here is what I'm currently seeing.

[image]

Thank you,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an AAD tenant. So I assume that your account is an Microsoft personal account.

Although you are added as the guest user in your client's tenant, the password management is not handled by that tenant. It is still handled by Microsoft personal account.

You can reset your password [here](https://account.microsoft.com/account?lang=en-us): click on **Sign In**, enter your account and click on **Forgot password?**.

Comment: Thanks Allen. I've been to that site several times over the last couple of days. My personal password does get reset, but I still cannot log into the client's DevOps. Continue to get incorrect password. I did edit my initial post to include what I'm seeing after entering my email address and before the password field is displayed. We don't have AAD tenant, and I didn't have a personal account to yesterday. Then the more than one account option started to be displayed. So when the client added me as a guest, and I created the password, where did that get created?

Comment: @voidinutah If you try to log in [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) with selecting work account, what will happen? Now that your account is also a work account, it should have an AAD tenant, which manages your account.

Comment: I don't remember the work account password. I did try my personal account password with the work account, but that failed. When I try the forgot password, I'm back to the original problem, which I get "You can't reset your own password because password reset isn’t properly set up for your organization." I went back and selected my personal account, and was able to login and got to my personal DevOps, but can't access client's DevOps. You mentioned an AAD tenant should exist, then how would I access that to configure? I didn't have anything setup in Azure and still don't for the domain.

Comment: @voidinutah Is you account domain in this format: `***.onmicrosoft.com`?

Comment: No, it's not. I'm familiar with that email format with Azure subscription. The email I'm using is a regular site domain outside of Azure.